# I am using forms in HTML and it automatically fills input username as false

Tags: javascript, html

I am starting to learn HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I have experience in C# so I know the general concepts in programming. My problem is this:

I have a form that is pseudo login screen. I take a username and a password and then after clicking a submit button there is a alert that says "You have successfully submitted" and console logs a message that shows me the username and the password the user has used to "login". However instead of showing me the username it replaces the username with the word "false". Here is my code.

```js
let loginForm = document.getElementById("loginForm");
loginForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();

    let username = document.getElementById("username");
    let password = document.getElementById("password");

    if(username.value = "" || password.value == ""){
        alert("Ensure you input a value in both fields!");
    }
    else{
        alert("You have successfully submitted!");
        console.log(`This form has a username of ${username.value} and password of ${password.value}`);
    }
    username.value = "";
    password.value = "";
})
```

```html
<form action=""  id="loginForm">
    <h1 id="title">Login</h1>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your username..."> 
    <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your password...">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In the console, instead of getting:
"This form has a username of admin and password of admin"
I get:
"This form has a username of false and password of admin"

Comment: `if(username.value = "" || password.value == ""){` On this line, you accidentally put 1 equal sign instead of 2, so you are setting the value of username to false. Change = to ==, and everything should work fine

Comment: Typo.  You're *assigning* to `username` here: `if(username.value = "" || password.value == "")`

Comment: Thank you! I have searched for the answer for like 30 minutes. I guess because I am used to Visual Studio showing me errors like this when I use C#, I completely missed this because VS Code didn't show it to me. Thank you!